# How to resolve pydantic model is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, pydantic, orjson

I am having below pydantic models.

```
class SubModel(BaseModel):
    columns: Mapping
    key: List[str]
    required: Optional[List[str]]

    class Config:
        anystr_strip_whitespace: True
        extra: Extra.allow
        allow_population_by_field_name: True


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    name: str
    config1: Optional[SubModel]
    config2: Optional[Mapping]
    class Config:
        anystr_strip_whitespace: True
        extra: Extra.allow
        allow_population_by_field_name: True
```

When I am trying to do a `dumps` on this, I am getting `model is not JSON serializable`

```
from io import BytesIO
from orjson import dumps
    
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
bucket.upload(BytesIO(dumps(data)), key, ExtraArgs={'ContentType': 'application/json'})
```

Error -

```
TypeError: Type is not JSON serializable: MyModel
```

`data` is a normal python dictionary with one of item of type `MyModel`. Tried to use `.json()` but get `dict has no attribute json`.

I am stuck here. Can someone help me.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 19):

Got similar issue for `FastAPI` response, solved by:

```
return JSONResponse(content=jsonable_encoder(item), status_code=200)
```

or can be just like this:

```
return jsonable_encoder(item)
```

where `jsonable_encoder` is:

```
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
```

More details are here:
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/encoder/

Answer (score 3):

From my perspective, the best way is to use built-in Pydantic model method *model_dump_json()*

Like:

```
b = Book(name="King")
return web.json_response(b.model_dump_json())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

What about just setting a default encoder (which is used if all else fails)?

```
orjson.dumps(
    MyModel(name="asd"),
    default=lambda x: x.dict()
)
# Output: b'{"name":"asd","config1":null,"config2":null}'
```

Or with more nested:

```
orjson.dumps(
    {"a_key": MyModel(name="asd")}, 
    default=lambda x: x.dict()
)
# Output: b'{"a_key":{"name":"asd","config1":null,"config2":null}}'
```

If you have other types than Pydantic, just make a function and handle all types you have separately.

It also works with [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) library from standard library (for those that don't use orjson).

Answer (score 2):

In modern Pydantic, there is a method json()

```
b = Book(name="King")
return b.json()
```

In general, I could recommend to run **dir(b)**, and then you can see all the methods, properties, fields, and so on

Answer (score 1):

Here the problem is that pydantic models are not json serializable by default, in your case, you can call data.dict() to serialize a dict version of your model.

```
from io import BytesIO
from orjson import dumps

bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
bucket.upload(BytesIO(dumps(data.dict())), key, ExtraArgs={'ContentType': 'application/json'})
```

Answer (score 0):

With Pydantic v2 and FastAPI / Starlette you can create a less picky `JSONResponse` using Pydantic's `model.model_dump_json(...)` ([doc](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.0/usage/serialization/#modelmodel_dump_json)) by overriding `JSONResponse.render()` [(starlette doc)](https://www.starlette.io/responses/#custom-json-serialization)

> Pydantic can serialize many commonly used types to JSON that would
> otherwise be incompatible with a simple json.dumps(foobar) (e.g.
> datetime, date or UUID).

Also NaN, btw.

```
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from pydantic import BaseModel

class JSONResponsePydanticV2(JSONResponse):

    def render(self, content: BaseModel) -> bytes:
            return content.model_dump_json().encode("utf-8")
```

I think this is basically something like FastAPI's `jsonable_encoder()` plus `json.dumps()`.